# Providing internet access to private Ec2 instance using NAT instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was able to connect my private Ec2 instance to the internet through NAT instance.
wget google.com was successful.
But when I attached a NACL to my private subnet.I wasn't able to connect to the internet.Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my NACL.
10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24 are CIDRs of public subnet(which has the NAT instance)

private NACL inbound rule
[image]

private NACL outbound rule
[image]

Also, when I add rule to accept all traffic from internet.It works. Is it correct practice to add this rule ?

Comment: You also need to specify outgoing rules? Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, I have specified outbound rules as well. lEt me attach the screenshot

Comment: So everything works with default NACLs? There is not connection to the internet only when you use your custom NACL?

Comment: yes @Marcin. Doesn't work when I attach the custom NACL for private subnet

Comment: I seems to me you are not accounting for [ephemeral ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports), i.e. 1024-65535. Please add them, and recheck if you can. I think in your case they should be added to inbound rules.

Comment: @Marcin In case of inbound rules ? But I think all Traffic includes the ports as well

Comment: Your inbound rule 130 and 140, allow all traffic, but not from the internet. Only from subnets 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. Can you check with 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: @Marcin That's what I have mentioned in the last line that it works if I mention this inbound rule to accept traffic from internet i.e. 0.0.0.0/0.But is it a correct practice ?

Comment: If you want to allow your instances to access internet traffic you must allow it. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-no-internet-connection): "Ensure that the network ACLs that are associated with the private subnet and public subnets do not have rules that block inbound or outbound **internet traffic**".

Comment: @HMT Why are you changing the NACLs? Typically, NACLs should be left at their default settings (allow all) unless you have a specific reason for changing them (eg creating a DMZ).

Comment: @Marcin According to the docs , internet traffic has to be allowed on both inbound and outbound port. If it's there in the docs then I think this might be the best practice.But just one question how will whitelisting work in this case. If I only want to download certain libraries using the internet and not allow any api requests ? Also, please add this as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am creating NACL as part of my assignment

Comment: Oh, this is just for an assignment? What does the assignment say that has a requirement for changing the NACLs?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein They just wanted us to practice creating NACLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was due to blocking inbound internet traffic (0.0.0.0/0). From the [Instances cannot access the internet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-no-internet-connection) in AWS docs, to enable internet access of the instance using NAT, the following must be ensured:

> Ensure that the network ACLs that are associated with the **private subnet** and public subnets **do not have rules that block inbound or outbound internet traffic**. For the ping command to work, the rules must also allow inbound and outbound ICMP traffic.

Question from comments:

> But just one question how will whitelisting work in this case. If I only want to download certain libraries using the internet and not allow any api requests ?

If you know IP ranges of the public servers that these libraries are going to be downloaded from, then you could limit the internet traffic to only these ranges. But if the range is not fixed or unknown you have to allow all (0.0.0.0/0) internet traffic in the rules.

Generally, security groups are used as primary way of controlling network traffic. NACLs are good due to their their denying ability. Security groups can't explicitly deny traffic, thus NACLs are helpful in cases where you want to explicitly deny some IPs. But in your case, you are allow only traffic. Thus I think the use of **default NACLs** would be sufficient and could be considered.